# Get JSON and save as Variabel depending on ID

Tags: jquery, json

I got the following JSON Example. 
Now I would like that if i enter the url: http://url.de#1234, that all content of kunde -> 1234 is written to variables. How can this be done?

JSON:

```
{
"kunde": {
    "1234": [{
        "gender": "male",
        "firstname": "Karl-Heinz",

    }],

    "3214": [{
        "gender": "female",
        "firstname": "Annette-Heinz",

    }],

    "5845": [{
        "gender": "male",
        "firstname": "Anton-Heinz",

    }]
  }
}
```

JSFIDDLE to JS and HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/7atLe66g/

**UPDATE**

This does work, BUT not the HASH Grabber and inserting into the JSON Function. 
why not??

```
var url = window.location.href, idx = url.indexOf("#");
var hash = idx != -1 ? url.substring(idx+1) : "";

var json_url = "http://localhost/test/beispiel.json";
$.getJSON(json_url, function (data) {

    var t = data.kunde[hash][0];
    alert(t.gender + "  " + t.firstname);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're traversing through your child objects and are unsure if they exist you can use the hasOwnProperty method. Then you will not get a error. And some error handling would be nice too. In your ajax request you can specify an error function and catch unwanted side effects or maybe else wrap it in a try-catch block. But when the application is ready it should be error free.

e. g. if(data.kunde.hasOwnProperty("1234")) ..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

```
<script>
    var data = {
        "kunde": {
            "1234": [{
                "gender": "male",
                "firstname": "Karl-Heinz",
            }],

            "3214": [{
                "gender": "female",
                "firstname": "Annette-Heinz",
            }],

            "5845": [{
                "gender": "male",
                "firstname": "Anton-Heinz",
            }]
        }
    };


    window.onload = function() {

        var t = data.kunde["1234"][0]; 
        alert(t.gender + "  " + t.firstname); 

    }; 


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But if the JSON comes from the file via URL? 
var data = http://urlToJSON.json does not work

Comment: and if i put hash instead of 1234 it does not work either. [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.kunde[hash][0]')

Comment: Alright, i got it with the file from url. Now what does not work is if i try to catch the hash from the url and put it into the data.kunde[hash]

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET', 
                url: ' http://url.de', 
                data: { id: '1234' }, 
                dataType:'json',
                success: function (data) { 
                       console.log(data)
                }
            });
```

or

```
$.ajax({ 
                    type: 'GET', 
                    url: ' http://url.de',
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function (data) { 
                           var t = data.kunde["1234"][0]; 
                           alert(t.gender + "  " + t.firstname); 
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This is what i get in your second example: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r[1234][0]')

Comment: does not work. TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.gender')

Comment: Try alert(table[0]) or alert(table["gender"]) and make sure that the field you're trying to access is named 'gender'.

Comment: Does not work either. Can you answer my last question from the answer of @marko?

Comment: The last answer here V V V scroll down

Comment: i already got it with the other answer. But thanks for your afford, Gave you an upvote

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving your problem is using square brackets. `json['kunde']` is the same as`json.kunde`. So you can do the same and use the hash variable, as in `json.kunde[hash]`, which would effectively access `json.kunde.1234` if hash = 1234, etc.  (though using fields beginning with numbers are illegal in dot notation). Let me know if that makes sense or if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var jD = {
  "kunde": {
"1234": [{
    "gender": "male",
    "firstname": "Karl-Heinz",

}],

"3214": [{
    "gender": "female",
    "firstname": "Annette-Heinz",

}],

"5845": [{
    "gender": "male",
    "firstname": "Anton-Heinz",

      }]
    }
  }  
  var hashCode = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var gender = jD.kunde[hashCode][0]['gender'];
  var firstname = jD.kunde[hashCode][0]['firstname'];
  console.log(str);
```